# Reduce array of objects based on "category" property and sum "amount" property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON object formatted like this:

```
balance = [{category:"clothing", amount:"120.50"}, {category:"groceries", amount:"145.23"}, {category:"clothing", amount:"97.34"}];
```

And I want to reduce it down to something like this:

```
merged_totals = [{category:"clothing", amount:"217.84"}, {category:"groceries", amount:"145.23"}]
```

This is the code I'm currently working with, it's pretty simple, but not formatting the object as desired and shown above:

```
combineCategories = function (data) {

  var newData = [];

  for (var prop in data) {
    newData[ data[prop].category ] = 0; // set initial value otherwise it will be undefined
  }

  for (var prop in data) {
    newData[ data[prop].category ] += +data[prop].amount;
  }

  console.log(newData);

}
```

This returns:

```
// [Clothing: 195, Groceries: 140, Deposit: 995.6]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var balance = [
  {category: "clothing", amount:"120.50"}, 
  {category: "groceries", amount:"145.23"}, 
  {category: "clothing", amount:"97.34"}
];

var combineCategories = function (data) {
  var res = {};

  data.forEach(function (el) {
    res[el.category] = (res[el.category]) 
      ? res[el.category] += +el.amount 
      : +el.amount;
  });

  return Object.keys(res).map(function (el) {
    return {category: el, amount: res[el]};  
  });
}

console.log(combineCategories(balance));
```

[http://jsbin.com/neqeli/2/](http://jsbin.com/neqeli/2/edit)